# When we talk about entangling properties do we really mean we are entangling states, since properties are a classical description?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I am attempting to be more concise in my own explanations and have been advised that properties is the incorrect term to refer to when preparing quantum states. Is it more accurate to refer to a property as a state and are properties just used as a term for ease of communication?

Comment: can you clarify what is the connection with the title?

Comment: Someone asked the question on whether we can entangle any property and it made me think about whether it is right to even think about entanglement in terms of properties. Thinking about it more perhaps it is okay, since after when we measure entangled quanta we can classify their phenomena as properties.

Comment: If by properties you just mean "measurement observables", then it's probably more correct to say that these are entangled than "states" are. A single given state (or density matrix) can have some of its properties entangled with its others in a perfectly sensible way, but when two states "become entangled", they cease to be independently describable - they must be described by a single combined state.

Comment: Classical physics is false, so there are no classical descriptions.

Comment: Thank you @JordanTaylor for the extra clarification, this is exactly what I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this what you meant to ask, but to some degree, I think your statement is correct. What talking about entanglement, one needs to specify the bipartite structure with respect to which entanglement is being discussed.

This is more obvious when discussing "entanglement of particles". Particles have multiple degrees of freedom, so a given two-particle quantum state can be entangled with respect to some degrees of freedom and not others.

A standard case study in this context is a single-photon state in a superposition of different position states, something you might often see written as $(a_1^\dagger+a_2^\dagger)|\mathrm{vec}\rangle$. Is this an "entangled state"? It would appear not, as there is not even any obvious bipartite structure in the space considered. But at the same time, you could equally write the state as $|10\rangle+|01\rangle$, where in this notation $|nm\rangle$ represents a two-mode, $(n+m)$-photon state with $n$ photons in the first mode and $m$ in the second one. In this form, the state certainly looks entangled, and in fact this entangled can be transferred (at least in principle) to, say, a spin system, which you would certainly call entangled. A canonical reference is here ([van Enk 2005](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0507189)).

Similarly, one can have a quantum state which is entangled only with respect to some choices of bipartition. Consider for example a three-qubit state such as $|000\rangle+|111\rangle$. This is an entangled state with respect to any bipartition, but also, if you only have access to the last two qubits, it will look like the separable state $|00\rangle\!\langle00|+|11\rangle\!\langle11|$. Or as another example, consider $|0\rangle(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$. This clearly has some degree of entanglement, but it is also a separable (and product) state between first and last two qubits.

Comment: Thank you @glS for the very thorough answer! So are you saying that you can describe entangled phenomena as a state but also as separable states? If the states are separable is it possible to then describe them in terms of their measured observables?

Comment: I'm saying that you need to be careful how entanglement is defined. A state is entangled with respect to a given bipartition. This is often not explicitly stated because which bipartition one cares about might be obvious from the context, but in some situations it's worth stressing. Note also that there are other notions of entanglement which encode "purely global" correlations, see *genuine multipartite entanglement* etc